# graphql ExecutionContext not recognized by nest-keycloak-connect

Tags: graphql, nestjs, keycloak

I would like to authorize users in GraphQL in a NestJs project. I use nest-keycloak-connect for this.

Unfortunately, when calling query with "Authorization" set in Headers, I get the error: **[Keycloak] Empty JWT, unauthorized**.

So it looks like nest-keycloak-connect doesn't recognize that context comes from graphql.

However, when looking at the source code of nest-keycloak-connect, context is checked for http and graphql there.

So what should I do to make nest-keycloak-connect start using graphql correctly?

**nest-keycloak-connect context type checking**

```
export const extractRequest = (context: ExecutionContext): [any, any] => {
  let request: any, response: any;

  // Check if request is coming from graphql or http
  if (context.getType() === 'http') {
    // http request
    const httpContext = context.switchToHttp();

    request = httpContext.getRequest();
    response = httpContext.getResponse();
  } else if (context.getType<GqlContextType>() === 'graphql') {
    let gql: any;
    // Check if graphql is installed
    try {
      gql = require('@nestjs/graphql');
    } catch (er) {
      throw new Error('@nestjs/graphql is not installed, cannot proceed');
    }

    // graphql request
    const gqlContext = gql.GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext();

    request = gqlContext.req;
    response = gqlContext.res;
  }

  return [request, response];
};
```

**my auth settings**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/Products'),

    KeycloakConnectModule.register({
      authServerUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
      realm: 'users',
      clientId: 'users-service',
      secret: 'h1xAJnShNwPmxzySR8Y0d3fLh27iwPPh',
      policyEnforcement: PolicyEnforcementMode.PERMISSIVE, // optional
      tokenValidation: TokenValidation.ONLINE, // optional
    }),

    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloFederationDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloFederationDriver,
      autoSchemaFile: true,
    }),

    ProductModule,
    ProductImageModule,
    ProductAttributeModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: AuthGuard,
    },
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: ResourceGuard,
    },
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: RoleGuard,
    },
  ],
  controllers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Resolver**

```
//FindAll
  @Query(() => [Product])
  @Roles({roles: ['user']})
  async products() {
    const products = await this.productService.findAll();
    return products;
  }
```

**Header**

```
{
  "Authorization":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1N..."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding **Bearer** to the header

```
{
  "authorization":"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR..."
}
```